# using notify_listener - libpqxx

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I'm trying to listen for notify events using [libpqxx](http://pqxx.org/development/libpqxx/). I started by going off an example that extended `pqxx::notify_listener`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <pqxx/pqxx>

class Foo : public pqxx::notify_listener {

public:
  Foo(pqxx::connection_base &c): pqxx::notify_listener(c, "listen") {}
  virtual void operator()(int id) { std::cout << "HERE!" << std::endl; }
};

int main(void) {
  // set up the listener
  pqxx::connection con("...secret...");
  Foo listener(con);

  // loop forever ...
}
```

I couldn't get this working though.

I tried switching the name parameter to
`pqxx::notify_listener(c, "my_schema")`,
`pqxx::notify_listener(c, "listen my_schema")` and some others.

I am creating the NOTIFY events manually via a pgAdmin. no matter what I do, the functor doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you call `pqxx::connection_base::get_notifs()` or `pqxx::connection_base::await_notification()` in the main loop?

If not, you need to.

Comment: Nice catch.  That was not obvious from the doxygen documentation.