# have libpqxx subscribe to a channel

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am trying to listen to an event in a PostgreSQL database when a table is updated. The trigger is created in the database and I would like to have `libpqxx` listen to the trigger signal.

I have tried the following code:

```
pqxx::notification_receiver receiver(conn, "my_event");
conn.prepare("LISTEN my_event");
while (true) {
    // Some sort of receiver wait

    // Getting info about the channel
}
```

The code logic makes sense but the compiler is complaining that variable type `pqxx::notification_receiver` is an abstract class. How can I create a derived class to be able to subscribe to the event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using notify\_listener - libpqxx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828447/using-notify-listener-libpqxx)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. It looks promising. But I tried to implement it all day today with no success.